# How to correctly override a package method?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using atticmedia/anvard package in my project for social login/registration. What I need - is to send an email to a new user that registered with his social account. I know that I can do that directly in the package, but that is a bad practice. Is there any other way?

I wanted to override the User->save() method, but then I got reminded that it is also responsible for updating the models, so overriding is not a solution.

Comment: You don't want to override any method ;) Use `created` event listener for this http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk what folder and file do I have to put events in Laravel 4?

Comment: There is no such event structure in L4, so  feel free to create one, where you put your handlers, or use closure inline